# MySQL daisy chain replication with different replication binlog_formats

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6

This is very unconventional and not normally recommended but I need to know if this is possible so here it goes. I have two mysql clusters each with a primary and standby setup. Cluster A replicates to cluster B using statement based replication. We are using statement based replication because we have triggers set on cluster B we need to fire that won't fire with row based replication. I now have a temporary requirement for a project to have a cluster C with row based replication being used. Is it possible (I know it's crazy) to daisy chain the replication by setting up cluster C and have B replicate to C using row based replication? Or do all replicas HAVE to replicate using the same type of replication?

Comment: I assume you are not referring to NDB Cluster, Galera Cluster, or Group Replication?  But, rather, ordinary Master-Slave replication.

Comment: @RickJames that's correct